# Merge old Plist with new Plist

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

I have add new entities to existing Plist. New version of app crashes due to Plist inconsistencies.

How do I merge old plist data with new plist?

My Plist creation method is as follows

```
- (void)createEditableCopyOfFileIfNeeded:(NSString *)plistName
{
    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:plistName];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:plistPath];
    if (success)
    {
        return;
    }
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
    NSString *defaultPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:plistName];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultPath toPath:plistPath error:&error];
    if (!success)
    {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is *data migration* and it depends quite a lot on what you are doing with the plist. Could you give more information about what's involved with this plist?

Comment: Sure, Plist have a dictionary. I add a new 'key' to dictionary. eg: OldDic--> key1="aa" key2="bb"     newDic should be like this   newDic--> key1= "aa" key2="bb" key3="cc"

Answer (score 2):

I would include a *version* key in your plist to compare it with the version of the application. You can check the version of your application with the following snippet:

```
 [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]
```

Then, at the startup of the application:

1. Read the plist, if there is no *version* key, it will be *old version*.
2. If *old version* then perform data migration to current version, adding the non-existing keys with default values. Here I would take in account different version numbers for future updates.
3. Add the *version* key with the version of your bundle as a value.
4. Save the plist.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

1. Rename old plist e.g. old.plist
2. Read both plists from separate files
3. Merge information needed adding chosen information programatically to new plist
4. Save new plist merged

Comment: But I want this to happen in app launch

Comment: You can also write a short proxy class. When it will be asked for information, it will determine if the information is in old or new plist file and merge it on demand.

Comment: So read all the info needed at launch. You will need to write merging class or merge it with some text merging tool. You can do it textually after all